# Hibernate sql query processing slower then normal query

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am using hibernate with Struts2. Before I used only Struts2 with normal database query(Postgres). Right now I am trying to modify my database structure with hibernate. But the problem is that while I am modify my code in hibernate then its working too slow.

```
  public void evaluation() {
    try {
      String hql = "from OMRDetailsTable omrDetailsTable where omrDetailsTable.bar_code_no not in(select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') and omrDetailsTable.roll_no not in(select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') and omrDetailsTable.omr_error in('T','U') order by omrDetailsTable.roll_no";
      Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
      query.setCacheable(false);
      query.setReadOnly(true);  

      List<OMRDetailsTable> result_1 = query.list();

      Iterator<OMRDetailsTable> iterator = result_1.iterator();
      while(iterator.hasNext()){
        omrDetailsTable  = (OMRDetailsTable) iterator.next();   
        set_no = omrDetailsTable.getSet_no().toString();
        String queryques = "from SetWiseQuesDetailTable setWiseQuesDetailTable where setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm='A' order by setWiseQuesDetailTable.sl_no";

        Query query1 = session.createQuery(queryques);
        List<String> ansDetailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ansDetailsList.add(omrDetailsTable.getSl_no());
        ansDetailsList.add(omrDetailsTable.getBar_code_no());
        ansDetailsList.add(omrDetailsTable.getRoll_no());
        ansDetailsList.add(set_no)

        List<SetWiseQuesDetailTable> result_2 = query1.list();

        for(SetWiseQuesDetailTable setDetails : result_2) {
          System.out.println("Inner loop"+setDetails);
        }        
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I used above function for getting the data from database. I used the same method without hibernate that was working faster then the above code.

My hibernate configuration file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database</property>
<property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="connection.password">postgres</property>

<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping class="com.templateproject.table.LoginTable" />
<mapping class="com.templateproject.table.OMRDetailsTable" />
<mapping class="com.templateproject.table.RejectListTable" />
<mapping class="com.templateproject.table.SetWiseQuesDetailTable" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What is the reason for working slow?

For extra information : OMRDetailsTable have 15000 records and SetWiseQuesDetailTable have 300 records. Means It will iterate 4500000 times.

How can I convert above sub queries in Hibernate? I am new in hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

This code executes the same query in the inner loop every single time. It is not dependant on the result from the outer query. This would cause me to suspect that you have not migrated everything correctly. You would have the same result with this code if you just executed the the queries at the beginning and then wrote nested loops. The second query loads all matching records in the DB every time instead of some subset that corresponds to the entry being processed in your outer loop.

However, you should also be aware that hibernate may add extra joins to eager-load additional entities whose tables would probably not have been included in your original SQL. Yourconfig has query logging enabled. Are there additional tables in your joins? I have seen these additional joins along with subsequent lazy-load operations cause performance degradation with a factor in the 1000s.

Hibernate uses reflections, which is slower than compiled code, but I would not consider this, until I was sure that my code was fuctionally equivalent.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is my mistake in my code?

Comment: This query 

String queryques = "from SetWiseQuesDetailTable setWiseQuesDetailTable where setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm='A' order by setWiseQuesDetailTable.sl_no";

has no paramters. That means it always Returns the same result. To execute this query multiple times (or in your case, 15k times) in rapid succession is almost certainly a mistake. What is the relationship between the OMRDetailsTable entity and the SetWiseQuesDetailTable entries? Shouldn't there be a join or a filter on the second query that limits based on the current OMRDetailsTable?

Comment: Nathan is right, your inner query is the same every time, and is executed EVERY time the loop iterates.  So you probably see the same "Inner Loop: " in your resulting page for every of your outer objects.

You also should make sure your statements are in a logical order.  The inner query is defined, then some unrelated output is written, then the inner query is ran and printed.  Make it more sequential.

You also need to work on the names of your variables.